# Get all followers using LINQ to Twitter 

Tags: c#, linq, twitter, oauth, linq-to-twitter

I'm using LINQ to Twitter API for gathering followers for specific users on twitter.
I am able to get all IDs, and with those IDs I can request their screen name and other properties I need.

I do this in a batch of 100 users (as I understand - 100 per request is the limit).

I'm also using oAuth.

So now I am able to get the info on 350 * 100 = 35000 followers.

What if a specific user has let's say 100000+ followers. How do I gather info on all of them?

Comment: I think you will find this is the reason why Twitter limits you to 350 requests per hour as per [Rate Limiting](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're already dong User Lookup, like this, but I mention it just in case:

```
        var users =
            (from user in twitterCtx.User
             where user.Type == UserType.Lookup &&
                   user.UserID== "123,456,789,...,777"
             select user)
            .ToList();

        users.ForEach(user => Console.WriteLine("Name: " + user.Name));
```

As you know, you're limited to 100 IDs at a time, meaning that you'll need to make a lot of requests, which will take a long time.  Check out Twitter's rate limiting docs, which explain how many requests you can make and (more importantly) techniques that might help to avoid lower rate limits:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting

In LINQ to Twitter, you can access rate limit info through the Headers and other properties on your TwitterContext instance right after a query.

Another potential option is to look at Twitter's Partner Providers to see if they have the data you need:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-data-providers

Joe